# Dynamically add items to Listview in jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

I'm having a bit of trouble dynamically adding items to a listview in jQuery mobile. Basically I want whatever is input by the user in the textbox to be added to the list. I have the following code and can not figure out why the desired output is not appearing.

```
<script>
  var listCreated = false;
  function appendToList() {
    if(!listCreated) {
      $("#items").append("<ul id='list' data-role='listview' data-inset='true'></ul>");
      listCreated = true;
      $("#items").trigger("create");
    }
    $("#list").append("<li>");
    $("#list").append(document.getElementById(item).value);
    $("#list").append("</li>");
    $("#list").listview("refresh");
  }
</script>
<div data-role="content">
  <div id="items"></div>
  <input type="text" id="item" />
  <input type="button" value="Add item to list" onclick="appendToList()"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try creating the entire `li` then appending, right now, you're appending an opening `<li>` to the list, then the value to the list, not the new `li`

```
var value = $("#item").val();
var listItem = "<li>" + value + "</li>";
$("#list").append(listItem);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DVbGY/1/

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thanks alot, did not see this oversight.